# Can't add a column to CListViewCtrl control - WTL

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, wtl

I have basic dialog based window inherting from CDialogImpl in WTL:

```
class CMainDlg : public CDialogImpl<CMainDlg>
{
public:
    enum { IDD = IDD_MAINDLG };
    
    BEGIN_MSG_MAP_EX(CMainDlg)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_INITDIALOG, OnInitDialog)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_APP_ABOUT, OnAppAbout)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(IDOK, OnOK)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(IDCANCEL, OnCancel)
    END_MSG_MAP()

    LRESULT OnInitDialog(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/);
    LRESULT OnAppAbout(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/);
    LRESULT OnOK(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD wID, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/);
    LRESULT OnCancel(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD wID, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/);


protected:
    CListViewCtrl wndList1;

}
```

When initializing the dialog on the OnInitDialog I try to populate this List view which I created in the resource editor and named it **IDC_LIST**:

```
LRESULT CMainDlg::OnInitDialog(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
{
    // center the dialog on the screen
    CenterWindow();

    // attach via CWindow ( CListViewCtrl )
    //HWND hwndList = GetDlgItem( IDC_LIST );
    wndList1.Attach( GetDlgItem( IDC_LIST ) );
    
    wndList1.InsertColumn( 0,  "Column1" , LVCFMT_LEFT, 120, 0 );


    return TRUE;
}
```

But even after the call to InsertColumn I see no column, I've tried the other overloads for this function which require creating a [LVCOLUMNA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-lvcolumna) but it didn't work either. Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you verified that `wndList1` is properly attached to a ListView window?

Comment: @MarkRansom well I thought thats what I did with the Attach call

Comment: No, that's what you *tried* to do.  There's nothing in `Attach` that will verify that it's the proper window class for example.

Comment: @MarkRansom here's the deal the attach IS working I'm checking in the debugger and the handle is NOT null after the call. So on that end it's fine i believe

Comment: The handle not being null is irrelevant.  It has to be a handle to the correct window type.  If it isn't then every call you make to that object will silently fail.

Comment: @MarkRansom the handle is null before the attach call, and then not null after it. There's just this one control,, how could it be the incorrect window type? Also GetLastError returns 0 after it, and after the InsertColumn call as well

Comment: @heapunderrun hey, it's a LISTBOX :
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST,22,14,225,64,LBS_SORT | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP

Comment: @heapunderrun that's worthy of an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open your resource (`.rc`) file in a text editor, what type of control do you see specified on the line along with `IDC_LIST`?

If it is `LISTBOX` then you have a wrong control type. `LISTBOX` is for the List Box control (the `CListBox` class). For List Control (the `CListCtrl` and similar classes) the typical RC line would look like this instead:

```
CONTROL "",IDC_LIST,"SysListView32",LVS_REPORT | LVS_ALIGNLEFT | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP,22,14,225,64
```

In other words, if you use Resource Editor (in Visual Studio) then be sure you select the *"List Control"*, not the *"List Box"* from the set of controls offered in the toolbox. And if you want column headers, set the *View* property (under *Appearance*) to *Report*.

You might also want to set the *Sort* property (under *Behavior*) to *Ascending*; that will apply the `LVS_SORTASCENDING` style to the control.